# How can I prevent a Spy-specific config from carrying over to other classes?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

I have a script for Engineer and Spy. For Spy I have an ambassador script. How do I prevent the ambassador script from `spy.cfg` from carrying over to the `engineer.cfg`?